# 2 Activities how do I launch just one

Tags: android

Rookie here.

Building an Android application where I have an activiy to update the notification bar AND display the apps main screen.  The second Activity just updates the notification icon.

When I attempt to launch just the notification Activity both startup.

I have it's the fact that both my Activities have DEFAULT category:

```
       <activity android:name=".MyappMain"
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.ng.MyappMain" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>    
           <activity android:name=".MyappNotification"
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.ng.MyappNotification" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Here is the code to launch my notification activity:

```
            Intent intentx = new Intent("com.ng.MyappNotification");
        lamaIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.startActivity(intentx);
```

Can someone show me an example of a Broadcastreceiver launching a activity

Comment: Have you tried changing it so that they both don't have `category.DEFAULT`?

Comment: Yes, but to what?  And should I launch it differently?